# Regex Expressions for different lines- python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, newline

I am trying to match a regex expression between two lines. 
For example, if there were a segment of text like this:

```
\\[-16pt]
x = 5
print(x)     
\\
\thinhline
```

I would be trying to get a match for everything in between the first line and the last 2 lines. However, since the segment ends in 2 lines (`\\  \n  \thinhline`), I am unable to find a pattern that searches through more than one line. This is what I have but it doesn't work:

```
content = replace_section(r'\\\\[-16pt]',r'\\\\\n\thinhline',  content)
```

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([\s\S]*?)(?=\\\\\n\\thinhline)
```

Try this.Use `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/76

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=\\\\\[-16pt]\n)([\s\S]*?)(?=\\\\\n\\thinhline)')
test_str = "\\[-16pt]\nx = 5\nprint(x) \n\\\n\thinhline"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
import re
string = """\\[-16pt]
x = 5
print(x)     
\\
\thinhline"""

content = re.sub(r'(?<=\\\[-16pt\]\n)(.*\n)*(?=.*\n\thinhline)', "REPLACED!\n", string, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print content
```

Part of the problem is that you're in escaped backslash hell - your original string has escaped slashes, and then you've got to (maybe?) escape them doubly, and then you've got to escape the `[]` literals in your expression.

Part of the solution, is that you need to count beginning and ending lines. If you know you have one line at the start, match the `\n` once, and then `\n` again before your last line. Hopefully you can expand this and compile the regular expressions from variables in your function.

Lastly, you can use the `re.MULTILINE` (or `re.M` for short) flag that allows you to match multi-line text. Keep in mind that `.` doesn't match a newline, but `\s` should in this case.

With the code above, the output is:

```
\[-16pt]
REPLACED!
\
    hinhline
```